# React Native init did not generate any files

Tags: node.js, react-native

I used the "react-native init appname" to create my app and none of the files like app.js or android or ios folders generated for me. I only have a package.json, package-lock.json, and node_modules in the folder.

I used the same command a week ago to make a project and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using React Native version 0.56 which is not stable on windows 10 at all. I went into my package.json file and change the version of React Native to 0.55.4 and ran npm i and then react-native upgrade and my issues went away.